# Integral Conditions in PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to set up and solve the heat equation in 1D that conforms to conservation of energy. So intuitively in addition to the initial condition
$$u(x,0) = f(x)$$
the boundary condition would be
$$\int_0^L u(x,t) dx = k,\quad t\in (0,\infty)$$

But I'm not very familiar with multivariate calculus and PDEs in general so I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I'm not really looking for an analytical solution as I suspect it'll be very complicated, but it'd be nice if someone pointed me in the correct solution. I am hoping to solve this in MATLAB if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Please tell us typically about the PDE.

Answer (score 1):

Energy conservation holds, for instance, if you solve the heat equation with the homogeneous Neumann or periodic boundary conditions.